# Needing to change a column to false when Data Validation is changed

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query, data-validation

I am using Google sheets and have a cell that has data validation and I am putting check boxes (I4:I) for people when items are received, they need to be changed to "False" when the Data Validation cell (C2) is changed.

I'm new at this, but this is what I have, but I am getting a syntax error on Line 5.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getC2Notation() == 'C2' && 
      e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Outbound Parts'
    ) 
    e.source.getRange('I4:I'),"FALSE"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the code like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'C2'
    || sheet.getName() !== 'Outbound Parts') {
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRange('I4:I').setValue(false);
}
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much.